# Users Tree system, horizontal, self-join

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, tree

I have a user system, every user can register new one under him or under one who is already registered, also can be on the right side or the left so it will be multiple dimension tree. Every user has an id, and I have a table that contains user_id, its right and left.

The table here:

[image: Table Contain the User_r/User_rd]

So please anyone can help me with that?
i want a PHP script to build Table in Tree system :) thank you.

Comment: Help with what? We're here to help with programming problems, not design your system for you.

Comment: Yea that's what i am asking for :D

Comment: ok Ben, it is a fair question (in the making), it just needs a little work

Comment: The term you need to search for is `adjacentcy list`

Comment: i tried a lot, search and asked, i don't have the right solution.

Comment: making a hierarchical structure out of an adjacency list common problem with many clearly defined solutions.. you have but to google the right terms.